# jquery- unable to access individual elements that are part of list/select box in a web page form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access each individual element, ie option, defined for a list box (or drop down box).

For some reason the code I am using is not working. It is given below---

```
$(jQuery('input', $(this).parent('form'))).each(function() {
        element= $(this);

            textmsg=" Element # " + (count+1) + "...Name of this input element = " + $(this).attr('name') + " multiplechoice-" +  $(this).attr('multiple');
            textmsg= textmsg + "...Also, for this element, the value is " + $(this).val() + " and type =" +  $(this).attr('type');
            alert (textmsg);
         var listofoptions = new Array();
         type=$(this).attr('type');
         if(type=="select")//this means we have to go through the children for this select element, to obtain the values for each option
         {
             var elements= $('option', this);
             for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
            {
                // add $(this).val() to your list

                alert("Value of this option=" + $elements[i].val()); 
            });

         }
});
```

How do I make the above code work? Or can you suggest an alternative way of accessing each option value? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select **all** inputs you would need to use the `:input` selector and not just `$('input')` as this will select inputs by tag name and the select will be excluded.

So do

```
$(this).parent('form').find(':input')
```

Also, since there's no `type` attribute on a `select` element. You could use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead to check if it's a select.

```
$(this).is('select')
```

Edit: for the if statement i would do the following

```
if( $(this).is('select') )
{
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){ 
       alert( $(this).val() );    
    });            
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/BHmeF/2/)

Comment: @Intersellar_Coder -  I changed the initial jquery call as per your comment, I also changed the 'if' condition as per your answer- now the if condition is -- if ($(this).is('select')) -- however still I am not able to obtain any option value... Is this due to error in following-- --var elements= $('option', this);-- or is it something else... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

the select tag is not an input so it would never be a part of the selection

You could try

```
$("input, select")
```